# Ensuring Rollbar has reported error with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rollbar

Logic inside my class sometimes uses `Rollbar.silenced` to ignore some exception (so they don't get reported).

I'm trying to write a test which ensure that rollbar actually report error.

```
it 'does not mute rollbar' do
        expect(Rollbar).not_to receive(:silenced)
        expect(Rollbar).to receive(:error).with(any_args).and_call_original
        expect { query }.to raise_error(unknown_exception)
end
```

Unfortunately rollbar doesn't use in `:error`, `:critical`, `:warning` etc. methods when reporting unrescued errors.

I saw  `report_exception_to_rollbar` and `call_with_rollbar` inside rollbar [sourcecode](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/blob/master/lib/rollbar/middleware/rack/builder.rb#L11-L22) which are wrapped with `Rollbar.scoped`.

So I tried to test it with:

`expect(Rollbar).to receive(:scoped).with(any_args).and_call_original`

but it also told me:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(Rollbar).to receive(:scoped).with(any_args).and_call_original
       (Rollbar).scoped(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
```

How do I ensure that the exception is caught by rollbar and test it with rspec?

Answer (score 3):

The line you want to ensure runs is the [Rollbar.log call in exception_reporter.rb](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/blob/master/lib/rollbar/exception_reporter.rb#L7). (`Rollbar.error`, `Rollbar.warning`, etc. are just wrappers around `Rollbar.log`.)

Try this:

`expect(Rollbar).to receive(:log).with(any_args).and_call_original`

Comment: already tried that. does not work.
`           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments`

Comment: error is for 100% raised because `expect { query }.to raise_error(unknown_exception)` passes. Do you think it might be connected with test envorinment?

Comment: Ah, could be because Rollbar is disabled in the test environment. The standard initializer does that: https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/blob/master/lib/generators/rollbar/templates/initializer.rb#L16-L19

You could try removing those lines from your config/initializers/rollbar.rb , or set `config.enabled = true` before running this particular test.

Comment: `Rollbar.configuration.enabled` is `=> true` however still no calls to `:log` method

Comment: also: with Rollbar enabled I probably don't want to `.and_call_original` anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

`log` didn't work for me, but `error` did. Here is an example with ApplicationJob in a Rails app.

```rb
describe "ApplicationJob" do
  describe "rollbar" do
    context "when rollbar is included" do
      before do
        class EasyJob < ApplicationJob
          def perform(*)
          end
        end

        allow_any_instance_of(EasyJob).to receive(:perform).and_raise(StandardError) # rubocop:disable RSpec/AnyInstance
      end

      it "makes a call to rollbar" do
        expect(Rollbar).to receive(:error).with(any_args)
        expect { EasyJob.perform_now }.to raise_error(StandardError)
      end
    end

    context "when rollbar is NOT included" do
      before do
        class HardJob < ActiveJob::Base
          def perform(*)
          end
        end

        allow_any_instance_of(HardJob).to receive(:perform).and_raise(StandardError) # rubocop:disable RSpec/AnyInstance
      end

      it "does NOT make a call to rollbar" do
        expect(Rollbar).not_to receive(:error)
        expect { HardJob.perform_now }.to raise_error(StandardError)
      end
    end
  end
end
```